# Archive all the file uploaded on S3 in a particular session via fineUploade

Tags: angularjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, fine-uploader

I am using [fineUploader](http://fineuploader.com/) in one of my project on MEAN.IO , I am able to configure [fineUploader](http://fineuploader.com/) with angular so as to make a request on server to upload file to S3 bucket, which is working fine . What my requirement is I want to send the bucket owner a zip download link of all the files that uploaded in a particular session on S3. So that bucket owner can just download the zip of those file from the mail only .

I go through fineUploader document but could not find anything specific . I also google the solution but don't get any idea on how to approach for this .

Any suggestion or link to read will be very helpful

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you would do this:

1. Grab the list of files represented in your DB for a particular user/session.
2. Use the S3 API to [GET each file](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectGET.html).
3. Generate a zip file.  You haven't specified your server-side language, so I can't provide any code for this.
4. Send the file to your user via email.  You can do this via [Amazon's Simple Email Service](http://aws.amazon.com/ses/) as well.

This is a server-side process, Fine Uploader is out of the picture.